# Грамотное программирование. Обработка исключений

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch, обработка-ошибок

Хочу узнать, **насколько грамотным** является использование конструкции `try-except` просто с целью избавления от ошибки.

К примеру:

**Есть задание:** Дан массив a. Определить знакопеременную сумму
a1 - a2 + a3 - a4 ...
(Условный оператор и операцию возведения в степень не использовать.)

Я сделал так:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

try:
    Sum_even = 0
    for i in range(0,len(a)+1,2):
        Sum_even+=a[i]
except IndexError:
    pass

try:
    Sum_odd = 0
    for j in range(1,len(a)+1,2):
        Sum_odd+=a[j]              <------
except IndexError:
    pass

print(Sum_even - Sum_odd)
```

Если не использовать `try-except` во втором цикле `for` ( *указано стрелочкой* ), то появится ошибка:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

И я, чтобы не морочиться по поводу задания правильного `rangre` просто "ловлю" ошибку, игнорирую ее и продолжаю программу дальше.

Comment: Это костыль. Правильное решение - исправить алгоритм так, чтобы не вылезать за границу списка.

Comment: @sergey-gornostaev, использование `if-else` для "обнаружения" выхода за пределы списка не будет являться "костылем"?

Comment: Ещё лучше совсем без них.

Comment: Использование `if-else` вместо исключений хотя бы стоит дешевле в плане производительности. В вашем же случае можно вообще без условных операторов обойтись.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print( sum([a[i] for i in range(0, len(a) + 1, 2)]) - sum([a[i] for i in range(1, len(a) + 1, 2) if i < len(a)]) )
5
```

Согласен с @SergeyGornostaev и с @Philippe, правильнее будет так:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print( sum(v for i,v in enumerate(a) if not i%2) - sum(v for i,v in enumerate(a) if i%2))
5

a = [1,3,5]
print( sum(v for i,v in enumerate(a) if not i%2) - sum(v for i,v in enumerate(a) if i%2))
3
```

Comment: Но зачем? Можно же просто `sum(i for i in a if i % 2 == 0)`

Comment: Второй вариант не правильный. Если a = [1,3,5], то ответ будет 3, а ваша программа выведет 9

Comment: @Philippe согласен, исправился.